# PHP exit() instead of break inside switch

Tags: php, switch-statement

In a switch, I redirect the user in every case, is it safe to remove `break;` in this situation ?

```
switch ($action) 
{
    case "ActionA":
        header('Location: PageA.php');
        exit();
        break;

    case "ActionB":
        header('Location: PageB.php');
        exit();
        break;
}
```

Edit : the reason why I try to be careful is that one case can modify a user profil, one another can delete it.

Comment: Yes, it's not needed and safe to remove - you terminate the script, so nothing more will execute after `exit`

Comment: `exit();` will terminate the program execution.so `break;` is now unnecessary there

Comment: If you're exiting in every case, why not just put `exit()` after the `switch`, instead of repeating it every time?

Comment: @Qirel Although it won't matter in this situation, I have to state for correctedness' sake: it isn't necessarily true that nothing will execute after exit. A [shutdown handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php), an [auto_append_file](https://websistent.com/php-auto_prepend_file-and-auto_append_file/), and all objects' [__destruct() handlers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#object.destruct) would execute after the `exit()`

Comment: I would suggest to always put either `break` or `exit` in every case, otherwise weird errors may occur. (see doc of switch: https://php.net/switch part about leaving out the `break`). If you intentionally omit the `break`, rethink your strategy, it's so easy to accidentally change code/meaning/order and weird stuff starts to happen.

Comment: This is very simple to test on your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `exit();` terminates the program execution. So nothing will execute after `exit();`.So `break;` is now unnecessary here.

You can go directly like below:-

```
switch ($action) 
{
    case "ActionA":
        header('Location: PageA.php');
        exit();

    case "ActionB":
        header('Location: PageB.php');
        exit();
}
```